# Use css3 to target all children if x or more children exist?

Tags: css, sass

I've been scratching my head trying to target all children if *`x`* or more children exist.

I want to able to target all child elements if *`x`* amount of children or more children exist.

So far, I've been able to target all children if *`x`* amount of children exist *(see `.example-1`)*, and i've been able to target children after *`x`* child *(see `.example-2`)*.

But I need help with my `.example-3` to target all list items if *`x`* or more list items exist.

See all examples plus an `.example-3` boilerplate ready to go. https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/vghawo83/

```
/* if 3 li's exist make all li's red */

.example-1 {
  LI:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
  LI:first-child:nth-last-child(3)~LI {
    background: red;
  }
}

/* make all li's red after the second li */

.example-2 {
  LI:nth-child(n + 2) {
    background: red;
  }
}

/* if 3 or more li's exist make all li's red */

.example-3 {
  LI {
    /* Need help with this one please */
  }
}
```

If its possible to do this then my `.example-3` end result would look like this...

**Example 3 - If 3 or more li's exist make all li's red**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with purely just CSS *yet* but it *will* be possible in the future using `:has()`.

```
.example:has(> li:nth-child(3)) > li {
  /* styles for direct child <li> elements when there are at least 3 of them */
}
```

Right now you need to use JS to detect how many `<li>` elements there are and then add a class to the parent to apply the styles.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, looking forward to `:has`